# Tomcat 6 - stop / start remote windows server via command line

Tags: windows, tomcat6

Everything is basically in the title.

I need to know if there is a way I can stop / start Tomcat6 on a remote Windows server via command script.
I can map to the tomcat/bin folder so I can see the tomcat6.exe and other files, if that helps.

KPS